# How to display a Google Play Store entry in a WebView

Tags: android, google-play

I've seen this link in my browser: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android

I can load that into a WebView, but that experience is less than ideal because

1. The user has to sign in to install the app
2. If the user has multiple Android devices tied to his account, he has to choose which one to send the app.
3. That site isn't mobile-friendly

I want the Google Play experience encapsulated into one WebView...or just a View that I can put in my Activity so that I can offer the user a "cancel" button and go back to a different Activity in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Play Store is not designed to be embedded in an app.

You are welcome to use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` for that `Uri` (or its `market://` equivalent) and `startActivity()` to bring up the Play Store application to view the listing for your desired app.

Comment: Darn! Thanks, CommonsWare. :)